# Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: predictions failed for Fold1: alpha=0, lambda=1 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :

Tags: r, r-caret

this is my code, please help me fix it. I keep getting the error below:

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
control = trainControl(method ="cv", number = 5) 
Grid_ri_reg = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = seq(0, 1, 
                                              by = 0.1)) 
Ridge_model = train(x = train_cl[, -c(19)], 
                y = train_cl$Salary, 
                method = "glmnet", 
                trControl = control,
                tuneGrid = Grid_ri_reg) 
Ridge_model 
mean(Ridge_model$resample$RMSE)

Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: predictions failed for Fold1: alpha=0, lambda=1 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: predictions failed for Fold2: alpha=0, lambda=1 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: predictions failed for Fold3: alpha=0, lambda=1 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: predictions failed for Fold4: alpha=0, lambda=1 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: predictions failed for Fold5: alpha=0, lambda=1 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
Warning: There were missing values in resampled performance measures.Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
```

Comment: `train_cl <- na.omit(train_cl)` might help

Comment: did not help unfortunately

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, if you can, using `dput()`. It is very likely based on the error that there is missingness in your data, so that would be the first step - but it's impossible to help further without providing further information.

Comment: The question this code is for is part c below: Consider the Hitters data in the ISLR package, our objective here is to predict the salary variable as the response using the remaining variables. a. Split the data into a training and testing data set.
b. Fit a linear model using least squares on the training set and report the test error obtained.
c. Fit a ridge regression model on the training set, with ⁄chosen by cross-validation. Report the test error obtained.